# Where is the option to page through search results?

Tags: search, content-manager

When searching within Tridion, I am unable to find how to page through the results.

It is possible to select a folder that contains more than 500 components, use the advanced search feature and select 'components' as Type and change Show Results to be 500 per page. However, you are never able to see more than 500 results. There are no options to change page as far as I can see so why does it say Show Results '500' *Per Page*.

Please let me know if I am simply missing where the paging buttons are as this can become quite frustrating if you need to localise a large number of components at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pagination support is not available throughout the SDL Tridion CMS interface at all, that was a design choice.

In your user preferences you can set the maximum number of search results to 50, 100, 250 or 500. From that point onwards the search engine will never retrieve more search results than the number you set. The same counts for the number you set in an advanced search, the text "per Page" is indeed a bit misleading, since you will only ever get to see the first page.

Comment: Thanks Bart. As you say, I think it was the fact it states 'Per page' that was confusing but if this is not possible that is fine. Thanks.